# Visual studio Multiply CheckBox with NumericUpDown

Tags: c#

Ok so I have multiple checkbox's with a baseprice but I need to multiply a numericupdown so this would be the users input.

I thought this would work

```
    if (potatoes.Checked)
    {
    baseprice * NumericUpDown1.Value;
    }
```

but it does not :( any help? im using windows form apps c#

Say the ``baseprice for my first check box is $1.91 I want it to multipy the `NumericUpDown` with what the user inputs. to `txtTotal.Text`

Code for cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace IceCreamMelts
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates user input and returns true if valid
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool vaildInputs()
        {
            //At least one falvour should be selects
            if (cbChocolate.Checked == false && cbStrawberry.Checked == false &&
            cbVanilla.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select at least one flavour.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private void btnOrderNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if valid input, process the order
            if (vaildInputs())
            {
                //Calculate baseprice based on Scoop
                double baseprice = 0.0;
                if (tomatoes.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice = 1.91;
                }
                else if (peppers.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice = 2.32;
                }
                else if (onions.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice = 1.05;
                }
                else if (potatoes.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice = 1.50;
                }
                //Add price for toppings
                if (tomatoes.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice += 0.50;
                }
                if (peppers.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice += 0.50;
                }
                if (onions.Checked)
                {
                    baseprice += 0.50;
                }
                if (potatoes.Checked)
                {
                    (baseprice * NumericUpDown1.Value).ToString();
                }
                //Show the price form
                frmShowPrice showprice = new frmShowPrice();
                showprice.SubTotal = baseprice;
                showprice.ShowDialog();
                //Reset the form, once show price form closed
                cbChocolate.Checked = false;
                cbStrawberry.Checked = false;
                cbVanilla.Checked = false;
                rbOneScoop.Checked = true;
            }
        }
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you multiply, but you don't assign or pass the result of the multiplication to anything anywhere. Since the TextBox.Text property expects a string, try assigning `(baseprice * NumericUpDown1.Value).ToString()` to it...

Comment: ok so                 if (onions.Checked)

                {

                    baseprice += 0.50;

                }
                if (potatoes.Checked)

                {

                    (baseprice * NumericUpDown1.Value).ToString()

                }

The onions one works but i dont want it to add .50 i want it to multiply by the user input of the numericupdown. I tried what you had but says numericupdown doesnt exist in current contex

Comment: It means the txtTotal variable/field is not a part of the class that has the btnOrderNow_Click method inside it. Did you make a typo wrt to the textbox name? If not, remember which class declares/possesses the txtTotal textbox, and then you'll need to figure out how you can access that textbox...

Comment: its on my second form

Comment: You have some confusing code where you have for example `if (tomatoes.Checked)` set a base price then a few lines down `if (tomatoes.Checked)` you add 50 cents to it. Seems odd.

Comment: Feels like this should be in a model perhaps

Comment: so yea im trying to convert add 50cents to multiply with the numericupdown box

Comment: If you have a `NumericUpDown` on a (popup?) form: Am assuming some things while keeping it simple; you need to set the modifiers of NumericUpDown to `public`. Then use a `Form.ShowDialog()` and you fetch the amount, seek the documentation how to use a dialog form (it's a functionality of the `class Form` you are using already. This you would find interesting and will help you to think in seperating functionality. Mark Schultheis also mentioned models, this is a very different thing but overlaps thinking in 'what is important for this and not for that' - a basic non-written rule in coding.

Answer (score -1):

also, if this is not a property, you are missing a an equal sign,

if (potatoes.Checked)
{
baseprice =* NumericUpDown1.Value;
}

Answer (score -2):

if this is c# property, then you need a return value, if not where is the equal sign for the result

Comment: very odd, I guess whoever gave the answer a negative response has no clue what I am talking about, here what I mean,    /*
    *
    */
    public bool Done
    {
      get { return runCompleted; }
    }
    /*
    *
    */
    public bool Stop
    {
      set { stop = value; }
    }
    /*
    *
    */
    public bool GenBatch
    {
      set { genBatch = value; }
    }
    /*
    *
    */
    public bool MultiModeBatch
    {
      set { mulitModeBatch = value; }
    }